# Process doesn't finish completely If I do not run test in debug mode in c#

Tags: c#, nunit

I have test which executes another process and waits for the process to finish before going further in test. But I have noticed that the process exits even before finishing itself. And I do not want to provide any hardcoded time for the process to run as different machine can take different time for the process to finish.
The code looks something like this :

```
[Test]
public void test()
{
   RunProcess();
   //Assert process has put all the records in database
}

public static void RunProcess()
{
   var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
   {
      FileName = "cmd",
      Arguments = "/C " + argumentsForProcess,
      WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory
   };

   var process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);

   process.WaitForExit();
}
```

The interesting fact is that this process runs completely fine if i run the test in Debug mode

Comment: What is the value of `argumentsforprocess`? What does *But I have noticed that the process exits even before finishing itself* mean? How do you assess that a process has exited before finishing its work? Things that work in debug but not in prod are often timing (prod is too fast) related..

Comment: I'm passing this argument ' node server.js' to run the process and that calculated some data for every day in past. But I noticed that after doing the calculation for one day the process exits itself

Comment: You should report any error code, and probably redirect output / error streams to catch any process failures.

Comment: 90% of the time the answer is "run the process directly, not via cmd.exe". In other words, run node _not_ cmd.exe.

Answer (score 0):

For the time being, I found the below code helping

var process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);

```
        while (process.Responding == true)
            Thread.Sleep(10);
```

not always idle but seems to work fine